Django and multithreading
I have Django view:
def func():
    ...
    instance = ...create()
    func2(instance)
    instance.attr = attr
    etc...

So func() creates an instance, calls func2() and keeps on working.
def func2(instance):
    request = request(instance)
    wait response
    response.data.save()

The result of function 1 and function 2 are in no way related. Function 2 is related to output/input operations. Function 2 must be called by function 1 and must not block the operation of function 1. In the current project version, func2 is called with celery. But I'm not sure that's the right way, and it's better to call func2 with another thread.
def func():
    ...
    instance = ...create()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func2, args=instance)
    thread.run()
    instance.attr = attr
    etc...

Am I right? Thanks a lot!

Do you have to use Threads? If your OS can afford many threads for your server for millions of users then fine but I think coroutines should be your option here seeing that func() doesn’t require knowing if func2() has finished. That way the event loop can schedule func2() to run at it’s own convenience. If you understood this point but you need more clarification, I’ll write an answer else what am I missing?

But Django it's synchronous framework, how can I use async func? Or is it unrelated?

Django is not completely synchronous. Django supports WSGI and ASGI servers. Django has a WSGI server that it ships with which you shouldn’t use in production. But you can use a different WSGI server other than the default. You can also use ASGI servers over WSGI if you want.

Use celery tasks and await their response (celery supports this) & it's cleaner.
If you can't use celery or some other async package, then re-think your design and requirements.
I would avoid any multithreading in a gunicor/wsgi server.
It's always come back to bite me in some way.
